# How to use sudo with sftp through winSCP?

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, sftp

I found a few sources stating that I can use SFTP with a sudo user through an SFTP client (specifically winSCP). This link outlines all the steps I need to take, and it's still not working (https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su).

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

- I first connected to AWS-EC2 instance from my terminal https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html#ec2-launch-instance), then connected to winSCP. I was able to upload files through my regular ubuntu user.
- I followed all the steps here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381498/how-to-use-sudo-over-sftp-with-cyberduck), but still get the error message below. When starting a winSCP session with the sudo user:
- I selected SFTP for file protocol under advance site settings
  I used `sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server` for the SFTP server under advance site settings
  I selected `sudo su -` for shell under advanced site settings
  After attempting to login with the sudo user, I got the error message:

> Error: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) Authentication log (see session log for details): Using username "sudouser". Server refused our key. Authentication failed.

Since the winSCP instructions above said to disable password authentication, I also went into visudo (by typing `sudo visudo`) on my terminal while signed into the user “sudouser”. I tried to use "sudouser ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" and “sudouser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL”. I still got the same error message in winSCP.

- Does anyone know how to get a sudo user to connect over SFTP on winSCP while keeping my sudo password?
- Would I have to use a private key separate from the one I got from ec2?

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing SSH authentication and sudo authentication. Those are completely different things... The sudoers file does not affect how you can log in to the system as a whole, nor do your SSH keys have any effect on how sudo behaves.

Comment: It sounds like you are following the right directions for winSCP. I don't know why you're looking at cyberduck instructions if you're not using that package. Have you tried turning on logging to track the session.

Comment: @user1686 The first link in the question specifically answers the question of using sudo in a winSCP session. His changes to the `sudoers` file look correct and his winSCP config may be correct. Doesn't look like he is confusing anything.

Comment: @doneal24 thanks, I started using cyberduck and filezilla on Mac OS and then switched to winSCP on windows when I found the stack overflow solution above. I followed the solution exactly as written, I was just wondering if it is an issue with the key pair. How would I connect a private key to both the sudo user and to winscp?

Comment: In the Authentication section of the winSCP config you have the option to set a private key file or to use Pageant. The key you set here needs to be the key of the user logging in, e.g. the user running sudo and not that of the user being sudo-ed to.

Comment: @doneal24 that makes a lot of sense, thank you! Do you know how I can link the user running sudo to a new key pair?